# Problema con listOf

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

Me estoy importando una lista de strings por pacelable

```
val person = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<ProfilesModel>("file_path")
```

Y el caso es que cada item es una imagen, por ejemplo 4 imagenes, lo que quiero es que con un Slider me muestre una imagen cada vez que recorro el dedo, pero siempre me muestra una, la ultima.

```
val person = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra<ProfilesModel>("file_path")
        println("el file_path  del activity: " + Constants.BASE_URL_IMAGE + person)


        for (res in person!!){    

            val lists: List<String> = listOf(
                Constants.BASE_URL_IMAGE + res.file_path
            )    
            createSlider(lists)
        }
```

Como lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// 1. Crear la lista
val lists = mutableListOf<String>()

for (res in person!!){  
    // 2. Agregar elementos a la lista dentro del for
    lists.add( Constants.BASE_URL_IMAGE + res.file_path)
}
// 3. Crear el slider con los elementos de la lista
createSlider(lists)
```

Answer (score 3):

El error es crear el slider dentro del bucle for. Eso se hace que se cree un slider por cada imagen y el slider con la última es el único que queda visible.

En este caso no necesitas usar un for. Lo más sencillo es agregarle la base a cada path con la función `map`

```
createSlider(person!!.map { Constants.BASE_URL_IMAGE + it.file_path })
```

Comment: Las dos respuestas son correctas, muchas gracias. Marco como correcta la de @Lobos por ser la primera respondida